# Play 2.2 for Scala: is it possible to modify the session of an incoming request?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to use action composition to add a fake user to Session.

```
def GuestAction(f: Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
  Action { request =>
    var myUser = searchUser(request.session)
    if ( myUser == null ) {
       myUser = newUser()
    }
    f(request).withSession("user" -> myUser)
  }
}
```

In my controller there is

```
def action1 = GuestAction { implicit request =>
   // My code
   Ok()
}

def action2 = GuestAction { implicit request =>
   val user = request.session.get("user").get
   // My code
   Ok()
}
```

When I open Chrome and browse to the route pointing to "action1" and then to the route pointing to "action2", everything works fine: I got a new user and it is attached to the session. 
On the contrary, when I open Chrome and I browse to the route pointing to "action2" first, I got an error because my "request.session" is empty, and that's obvious: using `.withSession()` the session is attached to the `Result`, not to the incoming request.
So, in order to make this work, I need to attach the session key/value pairs to the incoming request - like it is possible in `FakeRequest.withSession()`, but there's no such method in `Request`.

What would you suggest in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very nearly there - but to get the maximum value from your Action composition, you should be able to make your "client" Actions totally unaware of the session - they really only  care about the `User` object after all. You want to be able to write:

```
def action2 = GuestAction { implicit user => implicit request => 
  // Do something with 'user', whether it's a guest or real
  println(s"My user is $user")
  Ok()
}
```

`action2` doesn't care how the `User` was obtained, but it can rely on one being available. To make this happen, `GuestAction` needs to be something like this:

```
def GuestAction(f: (User) => Request[AnyContent] => Result): Action[AnyContent] = {
  Action { request =>
    var myUser = searchUser(request.session)
    if ( myUser == null ) {
      myUser = newUser()
    }
    f(myUser)(request)
  }
}
```

The only remaining piece of the puzzle is putting a user into the session - which you can still do with a conventional `response.withSession()` as part of a successful login process.